# Is this an Elliptic Curve in Complex Plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves

How can you show that the complex number $(u,v)$, where $u,v \in \mathbb{C}$, satisfying the equation

$$P(u,v) = \sum_{i,j = 0}^{2} a_{ij} u^iv^j = 0$$

determines an elliptic curve.

Some Background-

I am reading I. M. Krichever's paper, “Baxter's equations and algebraic geometry”, in which he claims that the points $(u,v)$ form an elliptic curve in $\mathbb{C}$. As per my understanding, the form of elliptic curve in $\mathbb{C}$ is

$Y^2 = X^{3} + aX + b$

where discriminant is 0.

Comment: This is what is called reduction to "Weierstrass normal form" of an elliptic curve. There should be plenty information about it on any course about elliptic curves.

Comment: If you are looking for a more specific reference, in the book *Lectures on elliptic curves* by Cassels you will find the birational transformations required to bring $P$ into a normal form.